# Error compiling modiagram

Tags: errors, modiagram

**EDIT:** This question has been identified as a bug

---

Consider the following MWE as `t.tex` from the `modiagram` manual:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{modiagram}
\begin{document}
\begin{MOdiagram}
    \atom{left}{ 1s = {0;up} }
    \atom{right}{ 1s = {0;up} }
    \molecule{ 1sMO = {.75;pair} }
\end{MOdiagram}
\end{document}
```

I am trying to compile using `pdflatex` with the call

```
$ pdflatex t.tex
```

But compilation fails with the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { }\prg_case_str:onn 
                                                  {\l_tmpa_tl }{{up}{\MOdiag...
l.7     \atom{left}{ 1s = {0;up} }

?
```

I don't understand this error message (looks like LaTeX 3).

I have installed `modiagram` version `0.2b`.

Comment: Seems like a bug. I'll fix it and send an update to CTAN later today

Comment: Wow, that was fast :) Is there a workaround for now? Shall I close the question?

Comment: You can try `\ExplSyntaxOn\cs_new_eq:NN \prg_case_str:onn \str_case:onn \ExplSyntaxOff`. I apparently missed that `\prg_case_str:nnn` was renamed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bad behaviour is caused by a bug. A fixed version is being uploaded to CTAN. If you want to fix the bug although TeXlive 2012 was frozen apply the following patch to your `modiagram.sty` or download the latest CTAN version and copy the fixed `modiagram.sty` over.

```
--- modiagram-orig.sty  2013-04-28 19:20:46.706592761 +0200
+++ modiagram.sty   2013-04-28 19:21:46.342589577 +0200
@@ -1285,7 +1285,7 @@
                   { \draw (0,0) -- ++(\l_MOdiagram_AO_width_dim,0) ; }
                 \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
                 \tl_remove_all:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { ~ }
-                \prg_case_str:onn { \l_tmpa_tl }
+                \str_case:onn{ \l_tmpa_tl }
                   {
                     { up }
                       {
```

Comment: I'll also try to clean the code at least a bit: there are quite a few rough edges...

Comment: The fixed version 0.2c is now on CTAN: http://ctan.org/pkg/modiagram